# Remove commas and quote characters between quotes using csv_xs perl

Tags: regex, perl

I would like suggestions on how to remove comas and quotes within the quoted filed

Ex:
"11","a"bc","s"am,","t"om,"","15"

In the example above for the value a"bc, "" should be removed, for s"am, " and , should be removed and for t"om," " , " should be removed. I am using the following code with CSV_XS module but it is not working.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
#
use strict;
use Text::CSV_XS;

# Read the input filename from the command line
my $file = shift or die "Usage: $0 <csv_filename>\n";

# instantiate the CSV parser
my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new ({ binary => 1 }, escape_char         => '"',allow_loose_quotes  => 1); 

# open the input file for read
open my $inputFH,  "<", $file or die "$file: $!";

# open the output file for write
open my $outputFH, ">", "$file.out" or die "$file.out: $!";

my @out;             # declare variables outside the loops for better performance
my $outputRow;
my $inputRow;
while ($inputRow = $csv->getline($inputFH)) { # iterate over each row in the input file
  @out=();           # empty out the array which will hold our corrected fields
  foreach (@$inputRow) {   # iterate over each field in the input row
    s/[\0\|\n\r]//g;         # get rid NUL, pipe, CR, and LF characters
    s/\s+/ /g;               # change multi-whitespace to single
    push(@out,$_);         # push the corrected field on to an array
    print "Loop"
  }
  $outputRow = join('|',@out);  # create a pipe-delimited line from the corrected array

  $outputRow =~ s/^\s+//;  # trim leading whitespace
  $outputRow =~ s/\s+$//;  # trim trailing whitespace

  print $outputFH "$outputRow\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The docs say it should be able to handle your severly broken CSV by using `allow_loose_quotes` set to `1` and `escape_char` set to anything but `"`.